# batch script to Find and replace the first occurrence of the string in a Path string

Tags: batch-file

I want to replace first occurrence of specific string in the path string not all occurrence.

for eg:

```
set strpath=D:\Temp\Test\projects\Test
set strreplace=Test
set strpath=%strpath:%strreplace%=MyProjects%        
echo strpath = %strpath%
```

But it replace all occurrence like
    strpath = D:\Temp\MyProjects\projects\MyProjects

i need output like

```
 D:\Temp\MyProjects\projects\Test
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a function for your problem:

```
@Echo OFF
SETLOCAL Enabledelayedexpansion

:: By Elektro H@cker

set "strpath=D:\Temp\Test\projects\Test"

REM Call :REPLACE_FIRST "Variable" "word" "to replace word"
Call :REPLACE_FIRST "%strpath%" "Test" "Anything"
Echo %replaced_str%
Pause&Exit


:REPLACE_FIRST
Set "str=%~1"
Set "word_before=%~2"
Set "word_after=%~3"
Set "splited_str=%str:\= \ %"

FOR %%# in (%splited_str%) do (
    IF "%%#" EQU "!word_before!" (
        Set "replaced_str=!replaced_str!!word_after!"
        Set "word_before="
    ) ELSE (
        Set "replaced_str=!replaced_str!%%#"
    )
)

GOTO:EOF
```

Output:

```
D:\Temp\Anything\projects\Test
```