# How to replace only one instance of string in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've searched all over the internet, but to no avail. How would you only replace one finding of a string in batch? Let's say I have the code:

```
SET string=chair chair book
```

Is there a way to replace the word "chair" only once? To something like this?

```
chair book
```

I used the edit replace feature by doing

```
SET furniture=%string:chair=%
```

But that makes all the instances of chair disappear into

```
book
```

Do any of you guys have a solution?

EDIT : Sorry about any confusion, what I meant was the *first* instance of the string replaced. For example, given

```
chair chair chair book
```

And the word "chair", it would output

```
chair chair book
```

As for the second thought, I think I would only want one word replaced at the time. So given "chair"

```
table desk chair chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk
```

It would be

```
table desk chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk
```

I'm really sorry about the confusion, hope this clears it up!

Thanks,
LardPies

Comment: You can try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579214/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-the-first-occurrence-of-the-string-in-a-path-st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a simple `for` loop. Taking my provided code directly from an example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35487302/8667430) by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) - We take each word from your `String`, then simply check if it was already used in the wordpool.

**RemoveAllDuplicateWords.bat**:

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "String=table desk chair chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk"
set "newstring="

for %%i in (%string%) do (
  echo !newstring!|findstr /i "\<%%i\>" >nul || set "newstring=!newstring! %%i"
)
Set "furniture=%newstring:~1%"

Echo %furniture%
```

As stated by Stephan, remove `/i` if you want the filter to be case sensitive.

---

**EDIT:**

So from a misunderstanding on thread request, I bring an EDIT that will solve the users post (Hopefully). From his clarification, He/She want's to not remove duplicated words from a string, but rather duplicated words beside each-other.

**Before:** `table desk chair chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk`

**After:** `table desk chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk`

This process is simple but can get complicated. My process of doing this is to simply to compare each word, by the word before it, that comes in the string. This will take `Table Chair Chair Desk` or `Table Chair Chair Chair Desk` or `Table Chair Chair Chair Chair Desk` (You get the point) and change it to `Table Chair Desk`.

Because this script is pretty lengthy, you will not want to paste this for each string. An amazing solution to this is to `call` it. As I Turned it into a function. Bellow I will explain how to use it.

**Command:** `Call :RemoveMultipleWords [String You Want Edited] [New String]`

**Example:** `Call :RemoveMultipleWords String Furniture`

Please keep in mind you can also edit the original string it's self too. This means instead of `String Furniture` you can put `String String`.

**RemoveOnlyDouble+Instances.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | Original String's
Set "Furniture=table desk chair chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk"
Set "Food=Lasagne Fettuccine_Alfredo Carbonara Carbonara Culatello Breadsticks Tortano Tortano"

Rem | Call To Fix Function
Call :RemoveMultipleWords Furniture Furniture
Echo !Furniture!

Call :RemoveMultipleWords Food IntlianFoods
Echo !IntlianFoods!

Rem | Exit BATCH
Pause
Exit /b

:RemoveMultipleWords
Rem | Reset LoopCount
Set "LoopCount=0"

Rem | Process Each Item
for %%A in (!%1!) do (

    Rem | Get Current Word
    Set "CurrentWord=%%A"

    Rem | Set First Word
    If "!LoopCount!"=="0" (

        Rem | Set LoopCount
        Set "LoopCount=1"

        Rem | First Run
        Set "%2=%%A"

    ) ELSE (

        Rem | Upcoming Runs
        If "!LoopCount!"=="1" (

            Rem | First Word
            Set "LastWord1=%%A"

            Rem | Add LoopCount
            Set "LoopCount=2"

            Rem | Echo Results
            If not "!LastWord2!"=="%%A" (Set "%2=!%2! !CurrentWord!")

        ) ELSE (

            Rem | Next Word
            Set "LastWord2=%%A"

            Rem | Subtract LoopCount
            Set "LoopCount=1"

            Rem | Echo Results
            If not "!LastWord1!"=="%%A" (Set "%2=!%2! !CurrentWord!")

        )
    )
)
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: The question does say they only want it replaced once.  So if the search term is in there 3 times I would think they want the other two to print.

Comment: @Squashman Nah I don't think that was the OP's objective. If He/She has an issue with my script I can always update it.

Comment: Sorry about that late reply. Squashman was correct, I would like only one instance to be replaced. Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: @LardPies That then brings up allot of questions, do you want the first instance replaced, the second, the last? The statement `only replace one finding of a string in batch` is unclear but when used with `chair chair book` it looks like you're just wanting to remove duplicated words with a single instance. Could you please edit your post with extended details? I'm quite lost! - A second thought, lets take `table desk chair chair book chair candle lamp lamp desk`; would you want it to make it say `table desk chair book chair candle lamp desk`...? Thought would make seance if  that's your goal.

Comment: @John Kens, my apologies, I've edited the question to be more accurate

Comment: @LardPies I have Edited my response based on my new understanding for the question. Please let me know have any questions.

Comment: @John Kens My sincere thanks! Sorry about the extra work I've caused ya, really appreciate it :) Cheers.

Comment: @LardPies Did this solve your issue? I really hope this is what you where intending.

Comment: It did, quite nicely too! Merci, monsieur